# Can we get old value of cell without using onEdit() trigger in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function onEdit(evt) 
{
var sheet = evt.source.getActiveSheet();
var range =  evt.range;
var column = evt.range.getColumn();
var row =    evt.range.getRow();
var sheetName = sheet.getName();

if(range.getRow() >= 3 && range.getColumn() >= 2  && range.getRow() <= 15 &&  range.getColumn() <= 2 )
 {
  if(sheetName == "Emails")
  {
   Logger.log(evt.value);//current value
   //Logger.log(evt.oldValue);//old value            
  }
 }
}
```

I don't want to use above code for old value, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please describe why you do not want to use onEdit() and what exactly you want to do instead?

Comment: Hi  ziganotschka, I just wanted to create a logic for email notification by comparing the old and new value. I was trying create a function,if no modification on certain range for 2 days then send a notification email. Can  you please help me with the logic?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the explanations in your comment

> I just wanted to create a logic for email
>   notification by comparing the old and new value. I was trying create a
>   function,if no modification on certain range for 2 days then send a
>   notification email.

- You want to monitor a value and send an email if it did not change for two days
- To do so you need to store the value (and timestamp) after the last change, for which you can use [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html)
- You need a trigger that can be onEdit or [time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that will regularly check for the current value, compare it to the stored one and estimate either 2 days have passed since the last edit.
- Since you do not want to use an onEdit trigger, find below an adptation of your code to use with a time-driven trigger
- You can bind the trigger to your function by going to Edit->Current Project's triggers->Create new trigger
- Set `Select event source` to `Time-driven` and `type` and `interval` according to your needs, e.g. `Hour timer`, `Every hour`

**Sample:**

```
function checkUpdateStatus()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails");
  //Selects a range of 13 rows and one column starting with the third row, second column - adapt to your needs if necessary
  var range =  sheet.getRange(3,2,13,1);
  var values=range.getValues();
  var now=new Date().getTime();
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<values[0].length;j++){
      //the following lines will set-up script properties the first time you use them:
      if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ 
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('values '+i+"-"+j,values[i][j]);
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('timestamp '+i+"-"+j,now);
        //if script properties have been set-up already:
      }else{
        //use parseInt() if your values are integers, otherwise ommit it 
        var currentValue=parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('values '+i+"-"+j));
        //if the value is still the same - check how long it has been the same
        if(currentValue==values[i][j]){
          var timeDifference=now-(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('timestamp '+i+"-"+j));
          var days=timeDifference/1000/3600/24;
          if(days>2){
            //send email
          }
          //if the value has been changed, update the script properties with the new value and timestamp
        }else{
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('values '+i+"-"+j,values[i][j]);
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('timestamp '+i+"-"+j,now);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ziganotschka,thank you for sharing the code. It works fine for the first time. But after modification in the spreadsheet it kept on sending emails.  It does not reset the time stamp and value.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If you pass me a copy of your spreadsheet (please remove private information), I can have a look at it!